# Why doesn't mass-assignment of :id in Rails 3.2.3 raise an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

It appears that update_attributes doesn't allow me to change the id (so it IS protected), but why isn't rails throwing the same error it does for other protected attributes?

```
> rails new mass_assignment_test
> cd mass_assignment_test
> rails g model User name:string
> rake db:migrate
> rails console
>> u = User.create(:name => "ben")
>> u.update_attributes(:id => 5)
=> true
>> u.id
=> 1
>> u.update_attributes(:created_at => Time.now)
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity:Error
```

This is the model that rails generates (app/models/user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code in your model or is your test directly after running the generator?

Comment: The test is directly after running the generator, but I added the generated model to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id of a record is protected by Rails itself:

```
# activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1961
def self.attributes_protected_by_default
  default = [ primary_key, inheritance_column ]
  default << 'id' unless primary_key.eql? 'id'
  default
end
```

You can bypass this with:

```
u.update_attributes!({:id => 5}, :without_protection => true)
```

Also, please please do not do this. :)  It will make your code hard to maintain...

Comment: Right, definitely not something that should go into production code. It was from an edge case in a test suite that was having different behavior from what I expected.